# Figuring out what's wrong with my model

Tags: edit-mode, bones, error, parent, pose-mode

I figured out how to make the hair model move by a friendly user, but now my issue is how it's moving. The hair moves along with my base, however its movement is off timing. I can provide the file to my model through discord, just comment it below.[image]

Comment: if head moves more than hair, there is a possibility that you added head vertices to hair weight paint, check your weight painting and look if those hair bones doesn't affect head as well

Comment: I don't know how to use weight paint so I doubt that it has something to do with that. I tried anyways and all I saw was just blue. My whole model turned blue.

Comment: Hello, you can share your file here: https://pasteall.org/blend/ (copy paste the URL it will create once uploaded)